# async operation concurrency understanding

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

These queues manage the tasks you provide to GCD and execute those tasks in FIFO order. This guarantees that first task added to the queue is the first task started in the queue, the second task added will be the second to start, and so on down the line.
below code

```
let anotherQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.gcdTest.Queue", qos: .userInteractive)
anotherQueue.async {
    anotherQueue.async{
        anotherQueue.async{
            anotherQueue.async {
                print("task 6")
                for _ in 1...300 { }
            }
        }
        print("task 3")
        for _ in 301...600 {}
    }
    anotherQueue.async{
        anotherQueue.async{
            print("task 5")
            for _ in 700...900 {}
        }
        print("task 4")
        for _ in 5000...7000 {}
    }
    print("task 1")
    for _ in 9000...10000 {}
}
anotherQueue.async {
    print("task 2")
    for _ in 1...1000 {}
}
```

produces output

```
task 1
task 2
task 3
task 4
task 5
task 6
```

But when we run the same code in Concurrent it produces unpredictable output.
ex:- change first line of code to below line

```
let anotherQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.gcdTest.Queue", qos: .userInteractive, attributes: .concurrent)
```

output

```
task 3
task 2
task 1
task 4
task 5
task 6
```

By definition it states 
Tasks in concurrent queues are guaranteed to start in the order they were added…and that’s about all you’re guaranteed!

So, expecting a similar output which is produced by serial queue(by default). (task1, task2, task3, task4, task5, task6)
Please any one help me out, where i am going wrong.

Comment: Since  the tasks are executed in parallel, why to you expect the same order as the serial ones?

Comment: because Tasks in concurrent queues are guaranteed to start in the order they were added.

Comment: Yes, but the thread start and the `print` call are separated, the thread can start but it can be put to sleep before it ends up executing the `print` call

Comment: Its clear now, thank you Cristik,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line, GCD will always start the tasks on a queue in the order that they were dispatched to that queue. In the case of a serial queue, that means that they will run sequentially, in that order, and this behavior is easily observable.

In the case of a concurrent queue, however, while it will start the tasks in the queued order, for tasks that are dispatched quickly in succession, they may all start quickly in succession, too, running concurrently with each other. In short, they may start running at nearly the same time, and you therefore have no assurances which will encounter its respective `print` statement first. Just because the concurrent queue started one task a few milliseconds after another, that provides no assurances regarding the order that those two tasks encounter their respective `print` statements.

In short, instead of deterministic behavior for the sequence of the `print` statements, you have a simple race with non-deterministic behavior.

---

As an aside, while it's clear that your example introduces races when employed on a concurrent queue, it should be noted that because of your nested dispatch statements, you'll have race conditions on your serial queue, too. It looks like the sequence of behavior is entirely predictable on serial queue, but it's not.

Let's consider a simplified version of your example. I'm assuming that we'll start this from the main thread:

```
queue.async {
    queue.async {
        print("task 3")
    }
    print("task 1")
}
queue.async {
    print("task 2")
}
```

Clearly, task 1 will be added to the queue first and if that queue is free, it will start immediately on that background thread, while the main thread proceeds. But as the code on the main thread approaches the dispatching of task 2, task 1 will start and will proceed to dispatch task 3. You have a classic race between the dispatching of task 2 and task 3.

Now, in practice, you'll see task 2 dispatched before task 3, but it doesn't take much of a delay to introduce non-deterministic behavior. For example, on my computer, if, before dispatching task 2, a `Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.00005)` manifested the non-deterministic behavior. But even without delays (or `for` loops of a certain number of iterations), the behavior is technically non-deterministic.

---

But we can create simple example that eliminates the races implicit in the above examples, but still illustrates the difference between serial and concurrent queue behavior that you were originally asking about:

```
for i in 0 ..< 10 {
    queue.async { [i] in
        print(i)
    }
}
```

This is guaranteed to print in order on serial queue, but not necessarily so on a concurrent queue.